# C++ network library similar to Netty

Tags: java, c++, networking, netty

Is there any C++ network library similar to JBoss's Netty? I need an architecture where I can add protocol handlers to a list and process network packets as objects.

Comment: have you looked at cpp-netlib ?

Comment: Perhaps Qt might offer (thru QtCore) what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) although I wasn't especially happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [LibSoup](https://live.gnome.org/LibSoup), which is a C http client and server library. It has a c++ libsoupmm.